# Node js crash with multiple update (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use this code in my controller to update one or more projects in my DB.

```
 update: function(req, res) {

       var ids = new Array();

        for(var i =0;i<req.body.data.length;i++){
          ids.push(req.body.data[i]._id);   
        }

       ids.forEach(function (id,index) {

          dayModel.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, day){
              if(err) {
                  console.log("error");
              }
              if(day) {

                  day.worker =  req.body.data[index].lav_mail ? 
                                    req.body.data[index].lav_mail : day.worker;
                  day.date =  req.body.data[index].date ? 
                                    req.body.data[index].date : day.date;
                  day.hours =  req.body.data[index].ore ? 
                                    req.body.data[index].ore : day.hours;
                  day.project =  req.body.data[index].progetto ? 
                                    req.body.data[index].progetto : day.project;
                  day.activity =  req.body.data[index].attività ? 
                                    req.body.data[index].attività : day.activity;
                  try {
                  day.save(function(err, day){

                      //return res.json(day);
                  });
                }catch(ex){
                  console.log(ex.stack);
                }
              }
          });    
       });

}
```

Then in the router

```
router.put('/', function(req, res) {
  dayController.update(req, res);
});
```

When a user makes a lot of calls, NodeJS crashes.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: ids.forEach is not an async call. You'll need to use something like https://github.com/caolan/async to iterate over each one

Comment: You should also note that due to the "async" nature here the commented line `return res.json(day)` is not valid here. Perhaps you want to return all of the created objects ( not sure why ), or perhaps you just want to return a response when all creation is complete to say "ok" ( i.e `res.status(200).end()` or even `res.end()` ). But you need to repect the completion of calls and don't try and send them all at once ( that is your error cause ). Look at [`async.eachLimit()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) as a way to "limit" the concurrent operations.

Comment: Or [`async.concatSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#concat) for a "combined" response of all created objects.

Comment: `async.forEach(req.body.data,function (item,callback)`
not solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can use `async` module there is a way without it.
Following code will update one record after another and when done it will return array of days.

```
 update: function(req, res) {    
     var days = [];

     updateOne();

     function updateOne(){
         // get one data object from array
         var data = req.body.data.pop();
         dayModel.findOne({_id: data.id}, function(err, day){
             if(err) {
                 console.log("error");
             }
             if(day) {

                 ...

                 day.save(function(err, day){
                     days.push(day); 
                     // if no more data then return   
                     if(!req.body.data.lenght) return res.json(days);
                     // otherwise update another one
                     updateOne();
                 });
             }
        });
    }
}
```